# Calling an ASP generated button click from a javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've following button on my web control,

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" Text="Save" onclick="btnSave_Click"  OnClientClick="myShowWaitScreenWithNoClose('Processing...', 'Saving survey.Please wait it may take minutes..');" CssClass="buttons" Height="46px" Width="212px" Visible="false"  />
```

and I'm trying to click this button using JavaScript from code behind. Like,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 if (!IsPostBack)
   {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "scr", "setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('btnSave').click(); return false;}, 180000);", true);
   }
}
```

But it throws an error `Error: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is returning null most likely because the id of the btnSave control is changed when it's rendered on the client side unless you use [CliendIDMode="static"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

For your code to work, you need to change it to:

```
  if (!IsPostBack)
   {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "scr", "setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('"+btnSave.ClientID+"').click(); return false;}, 180000);", true);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

It throws this error because the ID you declare is not the same as what is rendered.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSave" clientIdMode="static">
```

Add the `clientIdMode="static"` attribute so your ID will render exactly as your declared it.

Answer (score 1):

To get a server-side control via `Javascript`, use the below

```
document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click();
```

Comment: Tried following but same error,

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "scr", "setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('<%=btnSave.ClientID%>').click(); return false;}, 180000);", true);